# Is there any web software to log syslog evens?

Tags: syslog

Is there any good website to keep Syslog events? I need a website to manage Syslog events and group them based on their priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [software](http://loggly.com). This what I am looking for but it still in beta :(

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/)

Comment: I found that splunk eats a lot of ressources on the server it's installed on, even with a small config. And beware of the spam you'll get from splunk (registration required for download).

Answer (score 1):

Fred's suggestion of Splunk is great, but it can be expensive depending on your log volume. Another (free) option would be [php-syslog-ng](http://code.google.com/p/php-syslog-ng/). You'll need to configure your logs to dump into MySQL to take advantage of this, but once you do that, it's a very nice product.

Comment: +1 for Splunk being expensive for anything beyond the 500Mb (I believe) for their "free" offering.

Comment: Their pricing model is very strange — free... free... free... free... eight billion dollars!

Answer (score 1):

I use Adiscon LogAnalyzer.  It's been awhile since I've touched it, but seem to remember it is a few PHP scripts.  I Installed Apache HTTPD, configured the scripts to point to my syslog files and that was about it.

Answer (score 1):

[Octopussy](http://www.octopussy.pm) is another free package you might want to check out.